# Pandas - Remove index after stacking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've stacked a Series into rows. The index showing in my DF is showing a 0 and I am wanting to remove this. I've tried dropping level 0 when resetting the index but this doesn't work.
Here is some info about my DF:

```
('type of ds:', dtype('O'))
('values:', array([u'1158', u'0.000000', u'2.000000'], dtype=object))
('index:', MultiIndex(levels=[[0], [u'Clicks', u'Cost', u'Event Conversions']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=[None, u'Event Name: Glucocil - Add to Cart']))
```

Here is my code:

```
   event3 = pd.DataFrame({
     'Event Conversions': pd.Series(microEvents),
     'Clicks': pd.Series(clicks),
     'Cost': pd.Series(costs),
     })


event3.columns.name = 'Testing'

stackEvent3 = event3.stack()
stackEvent3.name = 'values'
# stackEvent3.reset_index()
print('type of ds:', stackEvent3.dtypes)
print('values:', stackEvent3.values)
print('index:', stackEvent3.index)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'events.xlsx')
stackEvent3.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

it currently prints out:

```
   Event Name: Testing
0  Clicks                                    1158
   Cost                                  0.000000
   Event Conversions                     2.000000
```

I would like the result to be:

```
Event Name: Glucocil - Add to Cart
Clicks                                    1158
Cost                                  0.000000
Event Conversions                     2.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If need Series use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for remove first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
stackEvent3 = event3.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

If need 2 column `DataFrame` add another [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
stackEvent3 = event3.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index(name='val')
```

Comment: One may prefer to use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) to remove a level of index instead of the first `reset_index`.